# Why don't the newest versions of Mi-35Ms have retractable gear?

Tags: aircraft-design, military, helicopter

[Older versions of Mi-35 Hind](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QvUti2d6mgA) helicopters had wheel boxes so that they could retract their wheels while flying.

Why don't the [newest versions of Mi-35Ms](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V0SFlVAyIXc) have wheel boxes?

Answer (score 2):

Quick answer: *because Russian engineers don't like fancy stuff* ;)

Long answer:

Fixed landing gears are common on helicopters even very recent ones, just look at French helicopter Tigre, Italian mangusta or American black hawk. 
It offers a very lightweight and robust solution for landing while allowing easy ground maneuvers and also offers crash absorption.